# Non-ascii filename for fopen()

Tags: c, file, character-encoding, ascii, cross-platform

I need a robust cross-platform solution to read a specific binary file in C. Let's say I want to [fopen()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/) such (maybe big) file, allocate a temporary buffer, and then [fread()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/) a sequence of bytes
to update my [SHA1_CTX](https://github.com/B-Con/crypto-algorithms/blob/master/sha1.h) and finally close my FILE, finalize sha1 and go on. Quite trivial, right?

But, there is one thing I doubt: What if the filename is not ASCII?
Let's say I will have:

- `/Users/me/Projects/my_file.bin`
- `/home/me/файлы/работа/мой_файл.bin`
- `С:\\我的檔案\\我的工作.bin`
- `D:\\Folder\\.bin`

Can fopen handle such paths? If not, what can I do? I may write some platform-specific code or look for some cross-platform library, but it is extremely important for my application to be as small as possible, moreover it is written in C, so QT, Boost, etc., are not applicable.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On essentially every platform except Windows, the expectation is that you pass filenames to the standard functions as normal `char[]` strings represented in the character encoding of the locale that's being used, and on all modern systems that will be UTF-8. You can either:

- honor this by ensuring that you call `setlocale(LC_ALL,"")` (or `setlocale(LC_CTYPE,"")` if you don't want to use other locale features) and treating all local text input and output as being in whatever that encoding is (making users happy but possibly making trouble when some external input (e.g. from network) in UTF-8 is not representable, or
- just always work in UTF-8, and hope passing UTF-8 strings through to filesystem access functions works by virtue of them being abstract byte arrays.

Unfortunately none of this works on Windows, but it [will work in the near future](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_in_Microsoft_Windows#UTF-8). It also works if you build your application with [Cygwin](https://cygwin.com/) or [midipix](https://midipix.org). Short of that, you need shims to make things work on Windows, and it's a huge pain.

Answer (score 0):

It is operating system specific and file system specific.

You might not know what encoding is used for the file path. The user of your program should know that.

However, in 2018, [UTF-8 tend to be used everywhere](https://utf8everywhere.org/). In practice, that is not always the case today (specially on Windows).

BTW, different OSes have different restrictions on the file path. On Linux, in principle, you could have a file name containing only a tab and a return character (of course that is very poor taste, and nobody does that in practice; for details read [path_resolution(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/path_resolution.7.html)). On Windows, that is not allowed.

> Can fopen handle such paths?

Yes. The C11 standard (read [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) for details) does not speak of character encoding.

A different question is what your particular implementation is doing with such paths. The evil is in the details, and they could be ugly.